# Dealing with IP Spoofing

Tags: routing, router, ip, ip-address

> Border routers, which are routers that span two or more sub networks,
>   can be configured to block packets from outside their administrative
>   domain that have source addresses from inside that domain.

Source: *Introduction to computer security(Michael_Goodrich,_Roberto_Tamassia under Network Serucrity chapter 5 (Dealing with ip spoofing))*

What does it mean, in layman terms?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that a packet received from outside the local network could have a source address of the inside network. That would be for a malicious purpose. The router could be configured to check the source address to see if it is received on the correct interface. Receiving a packet with the source address from the inside network on an outside interface would not pass the test.

Comment: This is a special case of Reverse Path Filtering, no? Reverse Path Filtering means that the router rejects *any* packet that comes in on an interface where if I wanted to reply to the source address, the packet would not go out via that interface.

Comment: Yes. Cisco has three modes of uRPF. See [Understanding Unicast Reverse Path Forwarding](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/about/security-center/unicast-reverse-path-forwarding.html).